# Tag for Beyond Earth

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't have enough rep here to create tags yet, but asked one of the first questions about Beyond Earth. The tag civilization-be was created, but I didn't find it until I looked at recent questions. Should the tag instead be beyond-earth, or should a tag description be properly added?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I retagged both questions to [civilization-beyond-earth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-beyond-earth), this just fits into the 25 character limit, so there is no need to abbreviate.